# Showing related data in a list

Tags: google-app-maker

I am building a page in Google AppMaker and cannot retrieve the latest record of the related data that was submitted.
In my app: I have multiple wounds, each with many inspection dates.  I want to be able to list each wound, and pull up the most recent measurements (latest Length, latest Width, and latest depth)
[Here is the Visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tt1zy.png).
I have tried advanced datasource options and did not get anywhere. I was hoping to use as little app script as possible. I thought this would be easily retrievable with the bult-in widgets (I can easily do this in spreadsheet using Vlookup... but I don't know what the equivalent would be in appmaker)  Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Make sure in your wounds datasource to prefetch inspections. Then introduce a table where the parent panel is set to wounds, drag in the table, scroll down in your datasource selector for the table and choose ‘wounds: inspections (relation)’.

Comment: Yes, I have made that mistake before. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a field that can be used as a criterion for getting the latest record, say CreationDate, then you can specify a sorting option in the relation settings.

[See sample One-to-many relation setting with sorting option (screen-shot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs09x.png)